# What color spectrum is nice for a content management - backend design?

Tags: content-management-system, usability

I know this question is pretty broad , but I think most of ya'l had used Content management systems and it is just a question what you really think about it, I sure that you have some conclusions of your own. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question.  What do you want to know?  The title seems clear, but the body of the question is hard to parse.  Could you simplify this or clarify it in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any neutral and balanced colour scheme which does not get in the way of users' effectively consuming the content should do. The colours themselves don't matter much, as long as there's enough contrast between the text and dominating background colours, and consistent colouring is employed throughout (i.e. menu has the same colour on all the pages).

I find the [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/) to be a very nice tool to pick a colour scheme. Its Vision Simulation feature could be quite useful, since it shows how users with various vision problems would see the original colours of the site.